# How can I force a file to use a specific version of php?

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a file which ran perfectly using php v5.6. When I upgraded my cpanel to php version 7.4 it stopped working. Is there any way of telling cpanel to run this file using php v5.6?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look there https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/set-php-fpm-version-per-directory.654575/#post-2672955 & https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360052624713-How-to-change-the-PHP-version-for-a-domain-in-cPanel-or-WHM

Comment: please consider adding some codes, errors, logs, or any useful information to your question to help others answer your question.